# drag and drop ordering of images

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, position

I have 5 images that go into a banner on my homepage. These images are stored in the database but what I would like the user to do is drag and drop them so they retain some order.

What I need to do is a

(i) drag and drop the images in a container div so left if position 1 and right is position 5.

(ii) on sumbit save the position as a field in the database.

Some pointers would be nice, probably use jquery if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it depends on what technology you are gonna be using, checkout if there's already a library you are using and already doing it... like angular material, if you already use angular. One of the simplest ways to go is, like others mentioned, using jquery sortable function

Answer (score 9):

Use [jQuery UI's Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) and it's associated methods to do a AJAX call to your server on state change.

Answer (score 8):

chk this out: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid